# Magento 2 - Understanding text/x-magento-init

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, jquery

I try to better understand the concept of [text/x-magento-init](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html).

I understand that it allows us to define script components that do a certain task, which we then can use as often as we like in any template.

I found this example in *vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\js\cookie.phtml*

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "mage/cookies": {
                "expires": null,
                "path": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->getPath()) ?>",
                "domain": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->getDomain()) ?>",
                "secure": false,
                "lifetime": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->getLifetime()) ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

By reading the documentation, I figured out that this means, a script is getting called once (because of the `*`). But where do I find the component `mage/cookies` to understand what it does exactly? And what if I use `body` instead of `*`, how does this change the logic?

**Bonus Question:** How to define our own component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mage/cookies` is JS component which initialized on the element with the selector specified as element selector.

[Syntax](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html) :

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    // components initialized on the element defined by selector
    "<element_selector>": {
        "<js_component1>": ...,
        "<js_component2>": ...
    },
    // components initialized without binding to an element
    "*": {
        "<js_component3>": ...
    }
}
</script>
```

If you'll add `body` instead of `*` then, it will consider as `element_selector`.

If you'll add `*` then it will provide data without selector.

For more details, You can [check here](https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-use-knockout-js-in-magento-2/).

Comment: But where is `mage/cookies` defined, where can I inspect its code?

Comment: You can check here : lib/web/mage/cookies.js

Comment: And if I want to create my own, do I have to put it in my theme or there? And when does it make sense to use an element selector?

Comment: You can use in theme as well as in module also. It's depend on your requirement.

Comment: I guess I have to create the same folder structure in my theme e.g. `mytheme/base/lib/mycustom.js` ?

Comment: app/design/[area]/[VendorName]/[themename]/web/mage/cookies.js It should be this path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104639/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-black).